# program to write values and the raise

Tags: plsql

I have to write program that generates file, which lines are of the next content:
EMPLOYEE_ID, OLD_SALARY, NEW_SALARY
For that I wrote a procedure that raises salaries for a given department, and program that generates that file. Now, my procedure is working just fine and when I compile a program it doesn't have any errors. But the problem is that it works wrong. When I execute it, I get this

```
108   12008   12008
109    9000    9000
110    8200    8200
111    7700    7700
112    7800    7800
113    6900    6900
```

OLD_SALARY column and NEW_SALARY column are same, and it didn't raise them at all. After second executing, columns are still same but the salaries are like 4 time after first executing.
I think the problem is in my cursor but I don't know how to solve it. Here is the entire code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY dir_vezba AS '/home/oracle/vezba';

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE raise_salary
IS
   v_deptno   NUMBER:=100;
   v_per      NUMBER:=0.2;
BEGIN
   UPDATE employees
   SET salary=salary*(1+v_per)
   WHERE department_id=v_deptno;
   UPDATE employees
   SET salary=salary*1.05
   WHERE department_id=v_deptno AND employee_id IN (SELECT e.employee_id
                                                    FROM employees e JOIN employees m 
                                                    ON (e.manager_id=m.employee_id));
END raise_salary;
/

SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
   v_deptno      NUMBER;
   v_oldsalary   employees.salary%TYPE;
   v_newsalary   employees.salary%TYPE;
   v_filehandle  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
   v_body        VARCHAR2(200);
   v_line        VARCHAR2(200);
   v_head        VARCHAR2(200);
   v_report      VARCHAR2(150);
   CURSOR emp_cursor IS
      SELECT employee_id, salary
      FROM employees
      WHERE department_id=v_deptno;   
BEGIN
   v_deptno:=extract_dep('POVECANJE_DEP.txt');
   v_report:='IZVESTAJ'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')||TO_CHAR(v_deptno)||'.log';
   v_filehandle:=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('DIR_VEZBA', v_report, 'w');
   UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_filehandle, 'Report generated on: '||SYSDATE||' for department: '||v_deptno);
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
   v_head:='EMPNO    OLD_SALARY    NEW_SALARY';
   UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_filehandle, v_head);
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
   v_line:='=================================';
   UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_filehandle, v_line);
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
   FOR emp_rec IN emp_cursor
   LOOP
      v_oldsalary:=emp_rec.salary;
      raise_salary;
      v_newsalary:=emp_rec.salary;
      v_body:=RPAD(emp_rec.employee_id,9,' ')||RPAD(v_oldsalary,14,' ')||RPAD(v_newsalary,10,' ');
      UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_filehandle, v_body);
      UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
   END LOOP;
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_filehandle);
END;
/
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question title so that it contains information about the problem. "Need solution for my program" will mean absolutely nothing to future readers here who are searching for solutions. We know you need a solution, or you wouldn't be posting here for help. Your title should explain something about the problem you're trying to solve or the question you're asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values in `emp_rec` are fetched before you call `raise_salary`, and won't be affected by the UPDATEs in `raise_salary`. To get the new value for the salary you'll need to fetch it from the database again. Try changing the main loop as follows:

```
FOR emp_rec IN emp_cursor
LOOP
   v_oldsalary:=emp_rec.salary;
   raise_salary;

   SELECT SALARY
     INTO v_newsalary
     FROM EMPLOYEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = emprec.EMPLOYEE_ID;

   v_body:=RPAD(emp_rec.employee_id,9,' ')||RPAD(v_oldsalary,14,' ')||RPAD(v_newsalary,10,' ');
   UTL_FILE.PUTF(v_filehandle, v_body);
   UTL_FILE.NEW_LINE(v_filehandle);
END LOOP;
```

Share and enjoy.